# Expanding ul with two columns on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wonder if I could trouble you for some help. I am in the process of creating the nav for a new site and am trying to achieve the following effect on hover:

If a li has a ul, this ul should gracefully expand in height downwards on hover of the parent li. But, it should also display the ul as two columns.

I have managed to get some way towards this, as show below: HTML first

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Top Link</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub Link 7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">News Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News Item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News Item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News Item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News Item 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News Item 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News Item 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News Item 8</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS second

```
header{border-bottom:1px solid #c6c8c9;
height:35px;
width:100%}
header nav{margin:0;
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0}
header nav ul{list-style:none;
margin:0;
text-transform:lowercase;
width:auto;
position:relative}
header nav li{float:left;
margin:0}
header nav li a{font:18px/1 'Arial';
height:23px;
display:block;
padding:7px 10px 14px}
header nav li:first-child a{padding:7px 10px 14px 0}
header nav li:last-child a{padding:7px 0 14px 10px}
header nav li:nth-child(2):hover,header nav li:nth-child(3):hover,header nav li:nth-child(4):hover{margin:-1px -1px 0 -1px;
border:1px solid #c6c8c9;
border-bottom:1px solid white;
border-radius:5px 5px 0 0}
header nav a:link,header nav a:visited,header nav li:hover,header nav li:active{text-decoration:none}
header nav li ul{background:#fff;
position:absolute;
top:44px;
width:504px;
-webkit-transition:max-height 0s;
-moz-transition:max-height 0s;
-ms-transition:max-height 0s;
-o-transition:max-height 0s;
transition: max-height 0s;
overflow:hidden;
max-height:0}
header nav li ul li{float:none}
header nav li:hover ul{max-height:155px;
border:1px solid #c6c8c9;
border-width:0 1px 1px;
padding:4px 0 10px;
-webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s;
-moz-transition: max-height 0.6s;
-ms-transition: max-height 0.6s;
-o-transition: max-height 0.6s;
transition: max-height 0.6s;
height:140px;
column-count:2;
-moz-column-count:2;
-ms-column-count:2;
-o-column-count:2;
-webkit-column-count:2;
column-gap:0;
-moz-column-gap:0;
-ms-column-gap:0;
-o-column-gap:0;
-webkit-column-gap:0}
header nav li ul{right:0}
header nav li ul li:hover{border:none !important;
margin:0 !important}
header nav li ul li a{font:16px/35px 'Arial';
opacity:0;
height:35px;
padding:0 0 0 5px !important;
left:0;
position:static;
border-left:6px solid white}
header nav li:hover ul li a{opacity:1;
transition:opacity 0.6s}
header nav li ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover,header nav li ul li:nth-child(8) a:hover{border-left:6px solid #c4004b}
header nav li ul li:nth-child(2) a:hover{border-left:6px solid #a7b600}
header nav li ul li:nth-child(3) a:hover{border-left:6px solid #ef9b00}
header nav li ul li:nth-child(4) a:hover{border-left:6px solid #5d406c}
header nav li ul li:nth-child(5) a:hover{border-left:6px solid #64884c}
header nav li ul li:nth-child(6) a:hover{border-left:6px solid #da6700}
header nav li ul li:nth-child(7) a:hover{border-left:6px solid #a03264}
```

and demonstrated at http://jsfiddle.net/Rwthwyn/mhu1Lgy2/ HOWEVER: what is happening is that the list items are filling up the space and appearing to load one at a time. What I would like them to do is just be of a fixed height in the first place and just appear, fully formed, as they are when the ul has finished growing.

To solve this, ideally I need to not add anything to the html as the menu is going to be part of a CMS site and I am not sure how many lsit items there will end up being. However, I am open to the solution involving some js or jquery if necessary.

In case I've not explained myself very well, feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: White space is a good thing.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Do you mean css white-space? Please could you explain how I could use that to help here?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can think of is to **remove** the use of css-columns:

```
column-count:2;
-moz-column-count:2;
-ms-column-count:2;
-o-column-count:2;
-webkit-column-count:2;
column-gap:0;
-moz-column-gap:0;
-ms-column-gap:0;
-o-column-gap:0;
-webkit-column-gap:0
```

and alter the selector

```
header nav li ul li {
   float: none;
}
```

to be:

```
header nav li ul li {
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
}
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mhu1Lgy2/4/

This will affect the order of your links, but that's something you can likely workout through your CMS. On a side note, you should really be better about adding proper whitespace and indentions to your code.

Comment: Do you know of a solution that doesn't affect the order of the links? Would whitespace help solve my issue?

Comment: To your first question: no, not without altering the html. To the second, whitespace is a reference to the **look** of your code, not it's functionality. You should put proper indentation and whitespace between codeblocks to make it easier for others to read your code. So, no. Whitespace does not solve the issue at hand, just makes it easier for others to help.